# Div разместить под div

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
Как разместить `div` с классом `save` под `div` с классом `task`

```css
.task {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.etap {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: grey;
}

.inf {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.save {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="tasks" data-open="1" class="task">
  <center><span style="font-weight:bold;color: #454545;display:block;">Этапы проекта</span></center>
  <hr style="margin:7px;">
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
</div>
<div id="task" class="inf">
  <center><span style="font-weight:bold;color: #454545;display:block;">Информация о задаче</span></center>
  <hr style="margin:7px;">
  <div id="divtask">
    Информция<br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="save">
  <input class="btn btn-raised mr-1 btn-danger" style='cursor:pointer;outline:none; ' type='button' onclick="location.href='';" value='Удалить'>
  <input class="btn btn-raised mr-1 btn-success" style='margin-left: 10px; cursor:pointer;outline:none;' type='submit' value='Сохранить'></div>
```

Comment: Сейчас будет сделано) Изи

Comment: а зачем вы им поставили им обоим display: inline-block; ? он как раз и заставляет их в одну строку располагаться.

Comment: @coder675 подскажите про какие блоки конкретно идет речь?

Comment: Я не сразу понял что вы хотели.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал **flex-box**

Ссылка на гайд - [ссылка](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Создал контейнер div с классом `divider`. В нем - 2 контейнера див с классами `d-left-part` и `d-right-part`. divider сказал, чтобы элементы внутри него были в ряд (flex-direction:row;), а .d-right-part добавил, чтобы элементы внутри него шли в колонку (flex-direction:column;)

```css
    .divider{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .d-left-part{
        width: 40%;
        margin-right: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .d-right-part{
        width: 40%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }


    .task {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .etap {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: grey;
    }

    .inf {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .save {
        width: calc(100% - (2 * 10px));
        height: auto;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

```html
<div class="divider">
    <!--  левая половина -->
    <div class="d-left-part">
        <div id="tasks" data-open="1" class="task">
            <center><span style="font-weight:bold;color: #454545;display:block;">Этапы проекта</span></center>
            <hr style="margin:7px;">
            <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
            <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
            <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
        </div>
        <div class="save">
            <input class="btn btn-raised mr-1 btn-danger" style='cursor:pointer;outline:none; ' type='button' onclick="location.href='';" value='Удалить'>
            <input class="btn btn-raised mr-1 btn-success" style='margin-left: 10px; cursor:pointer;outline:none;' type='submit' value='Сохранить'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-right-part">
        <div id="task" class="inf">
            <center><span style="font-weight:bold;color: #454545;display:block;">Информация о задаче</span></center>
            <hr style="margin:7px;">
            <div id="divtask">
                Информция<br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br> Информция
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я прошу прощения но div save должен быть под div task а не div inf

Comment: flex-direction: column; в таком случае

Comment: @Vladislav сейчас изменю

Comment: @Vladislav изменил... Но Ваш код ужасный.... Очень. Много ненужных, непонятный вещей

Comment: Постарайтесь его улучшить перед финальным предоставлением его кому-либо)

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно например save внутрь task вставить. В другом случае смотрите как на flex советуют делать.

```css
.task {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.etap {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: grey;
}

.inf {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.save {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 87%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="tasks" data-open="1" class="task">
  <center><span style="font-weight:bold;color: #454545;display:block;">Этапы проекта</span></center>
  <hr style="margin:7px;">
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
<div class="save">
  <input class="btn btn-raised mr-1 btn-danger" style='cursor:pointer;outline:none; ' type='button' onclick="location.href='';" value='Удалить'><input class="btn btn-raised mr-1 btn-success" style='margin-left: 10px; cursor:pointer;outline:none;' type='submit' value='Сохранить'>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="task" class="inf">
  <center><span style="font-weight:bold;color: #454545;display:block;">Информация о задаче</span></center>
  <hr style="margin:7px;">
  <div id="divtask">
    Информция<br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

```css
.task {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.etap {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: grey;
}

.inf {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.save {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="tasks" data-open="1" class="task">
  <center><span style="font-weight:bold;color: #454545;display:block;">Этапы проекта</span></center>
  <hr style="margin:7px;">
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
  <div class="etap">Задачи вне этапа</div>
</div>
<div id="task" class="inf">
  <center><span style="font-weight:bold;color: #454545;display:block;">Информация о задаче</span></center>
  <hr style="margin:7px;">
  <div id="divtask">
    Информция<br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br> Информция
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="save">
  <input class="btn btn-raised mr-1 btn-danger" style='cursor:pointer;outline:none; ' type='button' onclick="location.href='';" value='Удалить'>
  <input class="btn btn-raised mr-1 btn-success" style='margin-left: 10px; cursor:pointer;outline:none;' type='submit' value='Сохранить'></div>
```